# R - Aggregation taking into account NA values

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I have the following data frame:

```
File, Paragraph, Sentence, Entity
article1.txt, 1, 1, USA
article1.txt, 1, 1, Canada
article1.txt, 1, 2, Toronto
article1.txt, 1, 2, New York
article2.txt, 1, 1, China
article2.txt, 1, 1, Japan
```

I can aggregate by place on a file:

`occurrences<-rep.int(1,nrow(entity.locations))
entity.locations<-cbind(entity.locations, occurrences)`

`aggregate(occurrences ~ File + Paragraph + Sentence,
data = entity.locations[, c(1, 2, 3)], FUN = sum)`

So I have the result:

```
File, Paragraph, Sentence, occurrences
article1.txt, 1, 1, 2
article1.txt, 1, 2, 2
article2.txt, 1, 1, 2
```

Now I wanna do the same, having `NA` values:

```
File, Paragraph, Sentence, Entity
article1.txt, 1, 1, USA
article1.txt, 1, 1, Canada
article1.txt, 1, 2, Toronto
article1.txt, 1, 2, New York
article2.txt, 1, 1, China
article2.txt, 1, 1, Japan
NA, 1, 1, Ted Cruz
NA, 1, 1, Trump
NA, 1, 1, Hillary
NA, 2, 1, Putin
```

Where the expected result is:

```
File, Paragraph, Sentence, occurrences
article1.txt, 1, 1, 2
article1.txt, 1, 2, 2
article2.txt, 1, 1, 2
NA, 1, 1, 3
NA, 2, 1, 1
```

How I can aggregate, having or not more than `NA` values, without problems?
It is the solution in `na.action` parameter?

Comment: What is `occurrences`? Your code doesn't run as-is.

Comment: @alistaire, that variable is the number of entities per sentence. Please read the post again, focusing on two commands before `aggregate` function.

Answer (score 2):

Getting `aggregate` to work properly can be a little frustrating. In this case, you need to set `File` as a factor that includes `NA` in its levels, and give it occurrences to count:

```
df$File <- factor(df$File, exclude = NULL)
df$occurrences <- 1
aggregate(occurrences ~ File + Paragraph + Sentence, data = df, FUN = sum)
#           File Paragraph Sentence occurrences
# 1 article1.txt         1        1           2
# 2 article2.txt         1        1           2
# 3         <NA>         1        1           3
# 4         <NA>         2        1           1
# 5 article1.txt         1        2           2
```

The usual alternatives for such a task are `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(File, Paragraph, Sentence) %>% summarise(occurrences = n())
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: File, Paragraph [?]
# 
#           File Paragraph Sentence occurrences
#         (fctr)     (int)    (int)       (int)
# 1 article1.txt         1        1           2
# 2 article1.txt         1        2           2
# 3 article2.txt         1        1           2
# 4           NA         1        1           3
# 5           NA         2        1           1
```

and `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(occurrences = .N), .(File, Paragraph, Sentence)]
#            File Paragraph Sentence occurrences
# 1: article1.txt         1        1           2
# 2: article1.txt         1        2           2
# 3: article2.txt         1        1           2
# 4:           NA         1        1           3
# 5:           NA         2        1           1
```

Pick your favorite.